# What exactly is 駄目 in this 突っ込み?

Tags: meaning, spoken-language

> す、凄い破壊力です。わたし、思わず鼻血が出そうです！
>
> わ、私も
>
> なんの、俺は頭から血が出た。
>
> 駄目だ…ここは駄目人間の巣窟だわ

Context: The girl who said 「駄目だ…ここは駄目人間の巣窟だわ」to herself was watching the other three being stupid and playing with a cat and part way through this she says the above to herself.

Question: Who or what does 駄目 actually refer to? Originally I thought that it would be referring to those three above, which would also follow on with what she carries on to say (駄目人間), but when I hear someone say that, it would normally (in all times I can remember) be explicitly said like 「駄目だこいつ」 or 「駄目だこいつら」. Can anyone clarify what it is that 駄目 refers to, or how it is used here?

Comment: (性格)[改善の見込みがない](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E6%94%B9%E5%96%84%E3%81%AE%E8%A6%8B%E8%BE%BC%E3%81%BF%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you already understand the feeling of 駄目だこいつ or 駄目人間 used in this kind of comical situation. Then it's the same thing that is referred to here.

Simply put, she just said 駄目 twice for emphasis. You can think こいつら or 人間 is omitted in the first sentence. 「駄目だこいつら…ここは駄目人間の巣窟だわ」 or 「駄目人間だ…ここは駄目人間の巣窟だわ」 both makes sense, but these sentences sound a bit redundant to me.

You're feeling こいつ is somewhat necessary, and perhaps that's because 「駄目だこいつ…（早く何とかしないと…）」 is [a famous line from *Death Note* and is used like a set phrase](http://www.paradisearmy.com/doujin/pasok_dameda.htm). But grammatically the topic is not necessary in Japanese, of course. Actually people often say 駄目だ by itself and omit the subject (こいつらは, これは, 俺は, etc.) when *Death Note* is not in the speakers' mind.

Answer (score 0):

"駄目人間" = ""dead loss."

If you are at a loss about the first "駄目" in

> 駄目だ…ここは駄目人間の巣窟だわ

I would say it means something like

> Out of the question. There are nobody but dead losses here.

Comment: What do you mean by "out of the question"?

Comment: @roflcoptaz: "out of the question" = "unlikely to merit discussion."